# Is Stripe Checkout broken?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

The latest version of Stripe checkout looks to be buggy. I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'precision' of null on Stripe Checkout
```

On my checkout code. It's the same error on their tutorial page https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout

It's on this line:

```
function Geolocation(){}
Geolocation.prototype.setLocation=function(loc){
   this.precision=loc.precision;
...
```

This is on Chrome/Mac and Chrome/Linux... anyone else seeing it?

Comment: Works for me, Chrome/Windows, Chrome/Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure that `null` isn't a possible value that the code will pass to your `setLocation` callback?

Comment: Pointy, that's the stripe checkout code, not mine. Stripe dev answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on Stripe Checkout. We introduced a bug related to geolocating specific IP addresses at 00:34UTC and fixed it at 16:19UTC. It appears to have affected 49 users from a specific IP range over that period. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks narced133. All sorted now. Still, it makes me nervous having to reference the stripe checkout (or any 3rd party library) from your domain, rather than pinning on a known working version for this very reason.